# Golang - pass struct as argument to function

Tags: function, go

I have to parse some nested JSON, which translates into a Go type, like this:

```
type Config struct {
Mail           struct {
                   From     string
                   To       string
                   Password string
               }
Summary        struct {
                   Send     bool
                   Interval int
               }
}
```

Now I want to call a function for each key (Mail, Summary), I tried it like this: 

`utils.StartNewMailer(config.Mail)`

The problem is, how do I construct the called function, I tried to mirror the `Mail` struct (and called it `mailConfig`), since I can't pass an arbitrary struct as an argument.
`func StartNewMailer(conf mailConfig){ //...`, but that doesn't work either, I get the following compiler error message:

`cannot use config.Mail (type struct { From string; To string; Password string }) as type utils.mailConfig in argument to utils.StartNewMailer`

Do I have to pass in every single value to the called function or is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to mirror the `Mail` struct "?

Comment: The called function lives in another module, so I basically did there:
`type mailConfig struct {
 from string
 to string
 password string
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`utils.mailConfig` fields should be exported, as in the literal struct field in `Config` type.

```
type mailConfig struct {
    From     string
    To       string
    Password string
}
```

I suggest declaring inner structs as types themselves instead of using struct literals.

```
type Mail struct {
    From     string
    To       string
    Password string
}

type Summary struct {
    Send     bool
    Interval int
}

type Config struct {
    Mail
    Summary
}

func StartNewMailer(Mail mailConfig)
```